# Programmatically obtain Microsoft Band unique ID

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

Is there a way to programmatically get the band ID using the SDK? ie the serial number or any other means to distinguish between one device and another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Band ID is not currently exposed by the SDK. Currently, only the Band Name is exposed that can be used to identify a Band. You can add a feature request for a future version at: http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/